# How can I implement a Future which is woken up from another thread in Futures 0.2?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

I'm trying to find a simple way to implement the `Future` trait from the future crate, version 0.2.1:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::executor::ThreadPool;
use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::task::Context;
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

struct SendThree {
    firstTime: bool,
}

impl Future for SendThree {
    type Item = u32;
    type Error = Never;

    fn poll(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> Result<Async<Self::Item>, Never> {
        if self.firstTime {
            self.firstTime = false;
            thread::spawn(move || {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
                ctx.waker().wake();
            });
            Ok(Async::Pending)
        } else {
            Ok(Async::Ready(3))
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut fut = SendThree { firstTime: true };
    let mut executor: ThreadPool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();
    let result = executor.run(fut).unwrap();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2811c222b163b99511e0b15576335d4a&version=stable&mode=debug)

My problem is that the `Context` variable is not `Send` so I can't call `wake` from another thread:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `futures::executor::Executor: std::marker::Send` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:13
   |
19 |             thread::spawn(move || {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `futures::executor::Executor` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `futures::executor::Executor`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&mut futures::executor::Executor`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<&mut futures::executor::Executor>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures::task::Context<'_>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `&mut futures::task::Context<'_>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:19:27: 22:14 ctx:&mut futures::task::Context<'_>]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

If I change the code to this it works, but I can't do a `thread::sleep` without blocking:

```
if self.firstTime {
    self.firstTime = false;
    ctx.waker().wake();
    Ok(Async::Pending)
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to implement this?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields and `UpperCamelCase` for types. Use `first_time` instead, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Context` isn't able to be sent across threads, a `Waker` is:

```
fn poll(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context) -> Result<Async<Self::Item>, Never> {
    if self.first_time {
        self.first_time = false;
        let waker = ctx.waker().clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
            waker.wake();
        });
        Ok(Async::Pending)
    } else {
        Ok(Async::Ready(3))
    }
}
```

Note that this is a really inefficient way to implement timeouts. There are Futures-native methods that should be used instead.